# Is it possible to add webpart zone in sitepages?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation

I had a SharePoint site where I created a page (not a webpart page).  Can I add webpart zone on this page?

Comment: What you mean by Page? Is is aspx or html and how you add it?

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can.
Just open the page in SharePoint Designer and add web part zone on it.
Designer will automatically add the web part manager tag on the page too.

Comment: I tried to add it from designer but web part zone doesn't get displayed on the page.

Comment: It should show up when page is in edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

U just add your webpart in sharepoint site.
Then open your site in sharepoint designer.Find your webpart zone you added like so

```
  <WebPartPages:SPUserCodeWebPart runat="server" Description="My WebPart" Title="ContactUsWebpart" 
          AssemblyFullName="XTILTON.WEB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f58f965830ac0890" 
          SolutionId="a10addc4-93e8-4b4d-9bd3-41bd166e30de" 
          ID="g_c659e549_13c5_4c1c_8db9_c80e6d00fb88" ChromeType="None" TypeFullName="XTILTON.WEB.ContactUsWebpart.ContactUsWebpart" ></WebPartPages:SPUserCodeWebPart>
```

after that copy that webpartzone in your .aspx page. that's it.

Comment: actually i want to create 3 webpart zone on this page.is it possible?

Comment: Hi ARd,I never try that. But do it As i told U for single webpart

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that all mandatory ContentPlaceHolder from SharePoint master-page is linked to your custom page.

Maybe you should start design/create your custom page from native SharePoint web-part page, not start from scratch, to make sure all SharePoint functionality works well.

Answer (score 0):

Register your webpart at the top of the page using sample code below

```
<%@ Register tagprefix="VotingButton" 
             namespace="xx.org.SharePoint.WebParts.VotingButton"  
             assembly="xxx.org.SharePoint, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=ff75f32512e6d74c" %>
```

Next, add the web part to the web part zone area of page as below

```
<VotingButton:VotingButton runat="server" 
                           Description="VotingButton" 
                           Title="VotingButton" 
                           __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" 
                           __WebPartId="{58eb6642-70ed-450e-af72-e6062d07da2f}" 
                           WebPart="true" 
                           __designer:IsClosed="false" 
                           partorder="2" 
                           id="g_58eb6642_70ed_450e_af72_e6062d07da2f">
</VotingButton:VotingButton>
```

Comment: -1 The question is asking how to add a web part zone, rather than a web part.